# Connect SQL Server 2008 to Visual C++ Win32 Console Application

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, oledbconnection

Can anyone help me to connect SQL Server 2008 to Visual C++ win32 console application?
I wonder someone can published a sample code with header files that need to include.

Thank you for your bigger help since I am new to Visual C++.

Comment: Do you mean "connect an application to SQL Server"?  The other way around is an entirely different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DBDevVCOLEDB.aspx) is an article that uses OLE DB.